# Find the domain of $f(x)=\sec^{-1}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x-[x]}}$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

> Domain of $f(x)=\sec^{-1}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x-[x]}}$ is:

$$
x-[x]\neq0\implies x\notin \mathcal{Z}\implies x\in\mathcal{R}-\mathcal{Z}\\
\sec^{-1}:\mathcal{R}-(-1,1)\to(0,\pi)\implies \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x-[x]}}\in\mathcal{R}-(-1,1)\\
\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x-[x]}}\notin(-1,1)\\
x-[x]\in(0,1)\implies\sqrt{x-[x]}\in(0,1)
$$

The solution given in my reference is $\mathcal{R}-\{(-1,1)\cup\mathcal{Z}\}$, but how do I prove the part $x\notin (-1,1)$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure the "correct answer" is right. Consider $x=-0.8\in(-1,1)$, then $$\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{-0.8}{\sqrt{-0.8-(-1)}}\right)\approx\sec^{-1}(-1.789)$$ is defined (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to take the square root (and have a real result) we need $x - \lfloor x \rfloor \ge 0$ , but that is not a problem.

We cannot divide by $0$

$x - \lfloor x \rfloor \ne 0 \implies x\notin \mathbb Z$

For inverse secant to be defined we need
$\left|\frac {x}{\sqrt{x - \lfloor x \rfloor}}\right|\ge 1$

$|x| \ge \sqrt{x - \lfloor x \rfloor}\\
x^2 \ge x - \lfloor x \rfloor\\
x^2 - x + \lfloor x \rfloor \ge 0$

We know  $x - 1 <\lfloor x \rfloor < x$

If $|x| > 1$ we are safe.

if $0<|x| < 1$

$x^2 - x + \lfloor x \rfloor = x^2 - x < 0$

if $-1<|x| < 0$

$x^2 - x - 1 = (x - \frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 5}{2})(x - \frac 12 - \frac {\sqrt 5}{2})$

$x^2 - x - 1\le 0 \implies \frac 12 - \frac {\sqrt{5}}{2}\le x\le \frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt{5}}{2}$

What does that leave us with?

The domain is:

$x = \mathbb R - \mathbb Z - (0,1) - [\frac12 - \frac {\sqrt {5}}{2}, 0)$

Comment: Ok, so i guess my reference is wrong, atleast partially right.